# Open OnScreenKeyBoard to specific location on the screen

Tags: c#

**Platform**= Windows 7,C#

**Environment**=Visual Studio 2013

I want to open Windows builtin `OnScreenKeyBoard` on the required location of screen. Using following code i can open `Notepad` at desired location but failed to open  `OnScreenKeyBorad` "`osk.exe`"at my required location.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var prc = Process.Start("osk.exe");
        prc.WaitForInputIdle();
        bool ok = MoveWindow(prc.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 300, 200, false);
        if (!ok) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);
}
```

So can anyone help me, so that i can open `OnScreenKeyBorad` at my desired location of laptop screen. I also tried `SetWindowPos` but all in vain.

Comment: Look into `SetWindowPos`...

Comment: I also tried it but not succeeded